# Generate in the console an array of negative numbers

Tags: javascript, onclick

How to generate in the console an array of negative numbers with the click of a button?
I need the simplest way (no jQuery) - I'm a beginner.

```
<input type="button" 
       value="Generate in the console an array of negative numbers" 
       id="cmdSwitch"/>
```

Comment: No jQuery because you're not allowed to use it in homework?

Comment: You want a randon array of negative numbers or what ?

Comment: @hamism Look to the value of his input

Comment: How many negative numbers? Also, what's the required range of negative numbers?

Comment: Dosn't matter, for example from -10 to -1

Comment: - from global array numbersList

Answer (score 0):

You need a function that can be called later:

```
<script>
function generateArray() {
  for(i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    console.log(-Math.random());
  }
}
</script>
```

The `console.log(...)` can be used to output data. And `Math.random()` generates positive random numbers (fractional numbers between 0 and 1). As the numbers shall be negative we negate them with a prepended "-". The `for()` loop iterates 3 times ...

And you need to add a "onClick"-Event to your  Tag like this:

```
<input type="button" 
   value="Generate in the console an array of negative numbers" 
   id="cmdSwitch"
   onClick="generateArray();"/>
```

You can also write the whole function into the onClick-Event but this is bad coding style and would look like this:

```
<input type="button" 
   value="Generate in the console an array of negative numbers" 
   id="cmdSwitch"
   onClick="for(i=0; i<3; ++i) { console.log(-Math.random()); }"/>
```

If you want to output some string that looks like an array on the console you can do it like that:

```
<script>
function generateArray() {
  str = "[";
  for(i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    if (i>0) str += ", ";
    str += -Math.random();
  }
  str += "]";
  console.log(str);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sure, Andreas. I actually "interpreted" the question a bit, as I don't see a way to actually output a real array to the console. But of course we could output some string that looks like an array.

Comment: and also it is considered bad practice to put javascript code inside html property instead you can write you javascript inside <script> tag or in seperate file (you can cache it in this case )

Comment: Noohoow, don't do it like this. You can create an array with `var myArr = [];` above your loop. Than push it with `myArr.push(value)` and log `myArr`. See other answers

Comment: For a simple function it doesn't make sense to write a seperate javascript file. A seperate file would also increase page loading time. Especially if the user is connected via a slow link as GSM network with high latencies. However, if this script becomes large (e.g. whole library) or it is used by multiple html files in a project you are right.

Comment: It does already make sense to put it in a separate file if you want to use it on more pages. But that was not the question :P It's also better to use event handlers

Comment: @StefanK. I can't get why this code doesn't work. Please, help to correct mistakes http://jsfiddle.net/SantaUA/scn6mrtj/

Comment: @AndreasFurster con't get how to connect html code and JS, something wron in code jsfiddle.net/SantaUA/scn6mrtj

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
<input type="button" value="Generate in the console an array of negative numbers" id="cmdSwitch"  onClick="generateArray();"/>

funtion generateArray(){
   var newArray = [], 
       minNumber = 1000;

   for(var i = 1; i<=minNumber; i++){
       newArray.push(i*(-1));
   }
   console.log(newArray);
}
```

Comment: Where is the randomness?

Comment: @AndreasFurster Who said it had to be random?

Comment: Yeah, the question was just to generate array of negative numbers.

Comment: @plalx Whoops, i don't know. Just to make the boring questions a bit of fun? :P

Comment: - from global array numbersList